# Why is the survival of the sons of Korach not mentioned in Parshat Korach?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pinchas, parshat-korach

In Parshat Korach we read about the deaths of Korach and Datan and Aviram, and that the families of Datan and Aviram descended with them as the earth swallowed them up.

In Parshat Pinchas, when it is going through the census of the tribes, when it comes to the lineage of Reuven, it mentions Datan and Aviram and at that point it mentions that the sons of Korach did not die.

Why is that fact mentioned here? It seems out of place. Why not in Parshat Korach? And if it has to be in Pinchas at all then why not in a section about the lineage of Levi under Itzhar's descendents (thus showing he has surviving descendents from Korach too).

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you look carefully, by the time the story concludes it's become all about the followers and henchmen; Korach is pretty much moot. The verse actually says the pit swallowed Dasan, Aviram, and Korach's stuff.

By the time a fight gets big, whatever cause was technically the original spark is often forgotten.

Comment: CashCow was asking about Korach's SONS surviving , not just his henchmen ?!

Comment: I think that answered the question pretty well. The passuk doesn't mention it here to emphasize that mashal - Korach and his sons, who started the thing, don't matter once everyone forgot how things started. Thus, the passuk only focuses on his henchmen.